# Add Javascript Snippet Inside Textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea, code-snippets

I want to write a javascript inside a textarea without the javascript running. Displaying as some copyable text.

I'm using jquery to insert the textarea and snippet at the same time:

```
$("#copy-snippet-container").hide().html(data).fadeIn("slow");
```

Here's what I'm trying to insert which is formed using php and then sent to the jquery via ajax:

```
$snippet = 
'<script>'.
    'window.onload=function()'.
    '{'.
        'var p="email@email.com";'.
        'var a=document.getElementsByTagName("a");'.
        'var r=/https?:\/\/((?:[\w\d]+\.)+[\w\d]{2,})/i;'.
        'for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)'.
        '{'.
            'if(r.exec(location.href)[1]!==r.exec(a[i].href)[1])'.
            '{'.
                'a[i].href="http://www.example.com/add/"+encodeURIComponent(a[i].href).replace(/%2F/gi,"%252F")+"/"+encodeURIComponent(p).replace(/%2F/gi,"%252F");'.
            '}'.
        '}'.
    '}'.
'</script>';

echo '<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" value="'.$snippet.'"></textarea>';
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the snippet content between the textarea tags.

```html
echo '<textarea>' .$snippet . '</textarea>
```

Comment: Oh, I feel rather stupid now. Thank you for your wisdom in basic HTML! I will accept when the timer allows me! :)